# Install Perl in Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: perl, jupyter-notebook

Sorry if the question is too obvious.

I'm having problems with the installation of Iperl from

https://github.com/EntropyOrg/p5-Devel-IPerl.git

I know that anyway Jupyter has the option to run Perl code through %%perl but it could be annoying to add this to every cell.

The steps that I followed where the next:

-First I installed Perl

```
sudo apt-get install perl
```

-next, I followed the steps that they provide:

```
sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev ipython ipython-notebook libmagic-dev
git clone https://github.com/EntropyOrg/p5-Devel-IPerl.git

cd p5-Devel-IPerl
dzil build
```

(I did this step before discover that I have to run `cpanm --installdeps .` inside `/home/User/p5-Devel-IPerl`to install dependencies required)

```
cpanm --installdeps .

./bin/iperl console  # start the console

./bin/iperl notebook # start the notebook --> These commands doesn't work because my Ipython notebooks are located in Anaconda2
```

My questions are:

When I follow these instructions, the installation I guess is done outside of Anaconda2 and maybe because of that, it doesn't appear in the notebook.

How to do it to include it inside of Anaconda2?

If it is not possible, how to run it at least in a parallel notebook outside of `Anaconda2` parent folder?

Thank you a lot for any advice.

Comment: It seems that you can install additional kernels to jupyter: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

Comment: @Malj90 Any progress?

Comment: @PrimoPetri no. It was just to learn, but now I did not have much time to search more.

Answer (score 5):

You can check real documentation for Devel::IPerl module [here](https://github.com/EntropyOrg/p5-Devel-IPerl).

I could install it in my docker with Ubuntu, where I've installed the default Jupyter previously.

For IPerl I installed:

```
$ sudo apt install libzmq3-dev
$ sudo apt install cpanminus 
$ export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
$ cpanm --build-args 'OTHERLDFLAGS=' ZMQ::LibZMQ3
$ cpanm Devel::IPerl
```

After this, both the console and the notebook worked for me (I start it as described in the doc):

```
# iperl console
Jupyter console 5.2.0

IPerl!


In [1]: print "hello world!"
hello world!Out[1]: 1

In [2]: sub pow { $_[0]**$_[1] }

In [3]: pow(2,3)
Out[3]: 8

In [4]: pow(3,2)
Out[4]: 9
```

"Hello world" in IPerl jupyter:

[image: screen shot with opened IPerl notebook]

I've recently started to investigate IPerl for Jupyter, but it works really good so far.